# ARM template download access denied 401

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azureportal

I have contributor access. When I try to download an ARM template from azure portal, I get "access denied : 401" error. What could be the reason and how can I fix it? Strangely no one had this issue on google.

Comment: use developer tools to find out the actual error behind the 401? I doubt anyone would be able to help you based on this vague description

Comment: I second this. The reason for the 401 is generally in the response and usually tells you exactly what permission you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Azure CLI, Azure PowerShell, or REST API to export ARM templates.

**Azure CLI:**

```
echo "Enter the Resource Group name:" &&
read resourceGroupName &&
az group export --name $resourceGroupName
```

The script displays the template on the console. Copy the JSON, and save as a file.

Note: The export template feature doesn't support exporting Azure Data Factory resources.

**Azure Powershell:**

To export all resources in a resource group, use the [Export-AzResourceGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/Export-AzResourceGroup?view=azps-3.6.1) cmdlet and provide the resource group name.

```
$resourceGroupName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the Resource Group name"

Export-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
```

It saves the template as a local file. More options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-powershell#export-resource-groups-to-templates).

**REST API:**

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/exportTemplate?api-version=2019-10-01
```

Captures the specified resource group as a template. API Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups/exporttemplate).